# Hyperlink in DataGrid is not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a WPF application and in one user control I am using a hyperlink in DataGrid but it is not working . I am using bing.com just to test.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  Height="Auto" 
  Name="dataGrid1" 
  Width="Auto" 
  CanUserAddRows="False" 
  CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
  Focusable="True" 
  IsHitTestVisible="False" 
  BorderThickness="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=startTime}" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Time"   Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=endTime}" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resources"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=resources}" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Action"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=action}" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Result"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=result}" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Health"  Width="*" CanUserSort="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock >
                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.bing.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"><!--"{Binding Path=healthUri}">-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=healthUri}" Focusable="True" />                                                                                    
                        </Hyperlink>                                    
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why not simply use a [DataGridHyperlinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridhyperlinkcolumn.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

Hyperlink navigation can only occur if either the direct or indirect parent of a Hyperlink is a navigation host, including NavigationWindow, Frame, or any browser that can host XBAPs (which includes Internet Explorer 7, Microsoft Internet Explorer 6, and Firefox 2.0+).

You can do:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.bing.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">

private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thnx everyone. Stipo, this worked. Filburt, I am a newbie, will definitely try to use your hint.